# ScrollBar Windows Store App

Tags: c#, xaml, scrollbar, custom-controls

I'm trying to create my own control. And i'm stuck on adding scroll bars to it.

For test purposes i hardcoded the scroll bar values.

Here is my class:

```
public sealed class BarrelPanel : Control
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty VerticalScrollBarVisibilityProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "VerticalScrollBarVisibility", typeof(Visibility),
        typeof(BarrelPanel), null);

        public Visibility VerticalScrollBarVisibility
        {
            get { return (Visibility)GetValue(VerticalScrollBarVisibilityProperty); }
            set { SetValue(VerticalScrollBarVisibilityProperty, value); }
        }

        public BarrelPanel()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(BarrelPanel);
        }
    }
```

And here is my style:

```
<Style TargetType="local:BarrelPanel">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:BarrelPanel">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                        <ScrollBar Grid.Column="1" Maximum="10" Orientation="Vertical" Visibility="{TemplateBinding VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" ViewportSize="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The scroll bar takes part of a grid, when i set the visibility property to enabled:

```
<local:BarrelPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="White" Margin="722,212,0,0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="217" Width="150"/>
```

Example:

[image]

But it is not showing draggable rectangle or navigation buttons - why?

Comment: Is this just a learning exercise or something? Just curious why you wouldn't just use a ScrollViewer to handle your offsets/measures, etc.

Comment: because i wont scroll items like usually. I want to create a control in experimenting purposes, that based on scroller offset will rotate the items.

Something similar to datetime picker in iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer, more investigating the msdn on:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.scrollbar.aspx

My scrollbar didn't show up, because you **must** specify what type of scrollbar will be shown:

```
IndicatorMode="MouseIndicator"
```

or

```
IndicatorMode="TouchIndicator"
```

by default it is none.